# How loop download links with wget only by 2files , than wait until pdfunite merge the 2 files than remove to other folder

Tags: bash, for-loop, pdf, wget

How make wget - from links list- sequentially wait after downloading each 2 files (exam+correction) until merge them with pdfunite  ; remove them and keep the output and rename it [1..7].pdf

download only 2 files after wait 10sec until finish all links as they have th same name math.pdf and math-c.pdf they duplicated math.pdf.1 ect

```
for link in $(cat links.txt); do
   wget $link 
   let counter++
   if ! ((counter % 2)); then
       sleep 10
   fi
done 
do
    #math.pdf is exam and math-c.pdf is correction prefix of donwloaded files
    pdfunite math*.pdf [1.7].pdf && rm math*.pdf
done
```

Comment: Don't you have a syntax error of some sort ? What is the 2nd `do ... done` block for ?

Comment: merge the 2 downloaded files with pdfunite utility syntax :pdfunite input.pdf output.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This can do the jobs. The -O option of wget writes result in a file.

```
counter=0
for link in $(cat links.txt); do
   let counter++
   wget -O download$counter.pdf $link 
   if ! ((counter % 2)); then
      pdfunite download$((counter-1)).pdf download$counter.pdf  math$((counter/2)).pdf
      rm download$((counter-1)).pdf download$counter.pdf  
   fi
done
```

Comment: MERCI BEAUCOUP Mr Alain Merigot

Comment: More about wget  -O [UPPER O] options not to confuse with -o [lower o] (https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Directory-Options)